# Suggestions for iGoogle replacement/alternative?

Tags: windows, browser, rss

I've used iGoogle as my home/start page for years now, but have recently been notified that it's [going away](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664197%20going%20away) later this year. Apparently because there are mobile/chrome apps/plugins that do that same - though how either of them help me on a Windows PC with my preference for Firefox I don't know!

I mainly use it for aggregating RSS feeds from various development blogs, and from news sites. I also have a few gadgets such as weather forecasts.

(I would include an image so non-iGoogle users know what I'm talking about, but I'm too new to be trusted!)

So, my question...what are your ideas for replacements/alternatives? Either web based, or (Windows) desktop application.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Comment: You could rather use widgets in gmail and apps in chrome to make pure Google magic and simulate something very similar to iGoogle easily.

Comment: Could the question be moved to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ instead of closing? Actually there is http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28590/is-there-an-online-alternative-to-igoogle

Comment: That webapps post looks good (so many StackExchange sites! I guess I picked the wrong one), as do your comments to lonstar's post, so thanks for that @MichaelFreidgeim.

Answer (score 1):

My Yahoo does pretty much the same thing - can add in RSS/etc. There's also NewsGator, NetVines and of course Google Reader/Google News.

Comment: MyYahoo looks pretty close, I might give it a trial run. I must admit I hadn't even looked at Yahoo, they're kinda an 'also-ran' these days! Shame I can't get Google search on the MyYahoo page.

Comment: Yahoo is actually still doing quite a bit in terms of active content and developer support - they just don't have that fresh-faced boy genius or richer-than-God public persona to keep them in the news.

Comment: Many peoples suggest Netvibes http://www.netvibes.com/en (e.g. at http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3493931)

Comment: See also http://google-sucks.org/directory/index.php?c=21

Answer (score 0):

> **I really like iGoogle -- are there any other alternatives?**
>
> On your mobile device, [Google Play](http://play.google.com/) offers applications ranging from [games](http://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME) to [news readers](http://play.google.com/store/apps/category/NEWS_AND_MAGAZINES) to [home screen widgets](http://play.google.com/store/apps/category/APP_WIDGETS).
>
> If you’re a fan of [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome), the [Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore) provides a similar range of options like [productivity tools](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/app/7-productivity) and applications to [check the weather](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/app/65-weather-forecasts). In addition, just like iGoogle, you can [personalize Chrome](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes) with a theme.

That's from [here](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664197).  I thought it covered your requests for ideas on replacements/alternatives.

Comment: As per the note in my question, mobile/chrome related solutions don't really help me as I'm after a Windows or general browser related solution.

Comment: @GarethWilson As per my note at the bottom of the quote, I just took the whole section *as written* from the Google information page.  What I was curious about was why you made no mention of the reasons for rejecting Google's suggestions that **did** apply to your situation.

Comment: Sorry Bon, I don't follow. The only suggestions made on that page are for Android or Chrome which aren't any use to me. I didn't 'reject' any of Google's other suggestions as I don't see any other suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Myfav.es](http://myfav.es/). You wouldn't need an account and your settings will still be there if you don't clear cookies. However there are perks to having an account:

1. Your own custom url: http://myfav.es/username
2. Remembers settings even if you clear cookies
3. Use your facebook twitter, google or open id